# Command putty.exe in bat not executing when the bat is executed by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I created a bat file that connects to a remove server via ssh using putty.

I have the following pipeline

```
 "pipeline"{
   "agent any
triggers"{
      "pollSCM(""* * * * *"")"
   }"stages"{
      "stage(""Checkout"")"{
         "steps"{
            "git url":"https://github.com/example.git",
            "branch":"main"
         }
      }"stage(""Push image"")"{
         "steps"{
            "Dockerfile.bat"
         }
      }
   }"post"{
      "always"{
         "mail to":"example@gmail.com",
         "subject":"Completed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
         "body":"Your build completed, please check: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
      }
```

When I execute the Docker.bat by double clicking on my system. All the commands are executed successfully on the remote server, it connects and do all the stuff.

When I run my pipeline the putty command is not executed, all the other commands are executed.

My bat file is something like this

```
docker login -u dockeruser -p somepassword
docker rmi frombat
docker build -t frombat --file Dockerfile .
docker tag frombat mydockrep/myimage
docker push mydockrep/myimage
start C:\\putty\\putty.exe -ssh 100.200.300.400 -l root -pw somepassword -m substituir_imagem.txt
```

substituir_imagem is like this.

```
docker rmi mydockrep/myimage --force
mkdir /var/jenkins
docker run -d -p 80:3000 mydockrep/myimage
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Do you have any log error?

Have you tried to paste the commands in the pipeline using the [bat step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) instead of calling a bat file?

Have you tried to call 'putty' without the 'start' command? If it starts a new thread, maybe it's causing the problem